# How do I include a random effect in PERMANOVA (vegan)?

Tags: r, vegan, random-effects

Another newbie R question;
I have a few models structured similarly to this;

communitymatrix ~ variable1 + variable2 + (1|Random effect)

I want to run a permanova analysis and have structured it like this;

result <- adonis(communitymatrix ~ variable1 + variable2 + (1|Random effect), data = variables, permutations = 999, method = "bray")

which returns this error:

Error in 1 | Random effect :
operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types

... what does this mean, and how do I fix it? It all works as it should when I remove that component, so have I just coded it wrong?

(data names changed as am unable to share the data)

Comment: There are no random effects in `adonis`.